# Возможно ли удалить графику с panel, С# WF

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Под графиков подразумевается `DrawLine`, `DrawRectangle` и т.д.

`gr.Clear(Color.White);` не работает

код отрисовки

```
for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
{
    g.DrawLine(new Pen(massivC[0]), p[i][0].X, p[i][0].Y, p[i][1].X, p[i][1].Y);
}
if (mdown)
{
    g.DrawLine(new Pen(massivC[0]), p[cnt][0].X, p[cnt][0].Y, p[cnt][1].X, p[cnt][1].Y);
}
```

здесь заносится в массив p координаты моего курсора

```
if (mdown) // mdown отвечает за нажатие левой кнопки мышки
{
    p[cnt][1].X = e.X;
    p[cnt][1].Y = e.Y;
    panel1.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: покажите код, как вы рисуете

Comment: Нарисовать закрашенный белым прямоугольник пробовали? Размером со всю панель.

Comment: у меня видать из-за panel1.Invalidate(); при наведении на panel удаляется вся графика (кроме этих линий)

Comment: Нужно больше кода. | `Invalidate` в конечном итоге приводит к вызову события `Paint`. В этом событии графика и рисуется. Хотите удалить её - в `Paint` ничего не должно рисоваться, а старое стираться. Или, может, вы на графиксе битмапа рисуете?

Comment: Вынесите код сверху из Paint в другое место, и придумайте ему булевый флаг (или другой механизм), который будет решать когда рисовать данные линии а когда нет.